# A problem related to multivariate differential calculus.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am doubted with this following problem and can not understand how to proceed. Please help a little for solving the problem and the counterexample with it. I can not construct.

Prove that there is no real valued function $f$ such that $f'(c, u) > 0$ for a fixed point $c$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and every non-zero vector $u$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Give an example such that $f'(c, u) > 0 $ for a fixed direction $u$ and for every $c$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Thank you.

Comment: What is $f'(c, u)$?

Comment: Directional derivative of $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ at point $c$ in the direction $u$.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative operator $df_c : T_c\mathbb{R}^n \to T_{f(c)}\mathbb{R}$ is linear.  If it takes on a "positive" value at $u$ (we have to identify the tangent space to the reals at a point, which is a vector space, with the reals themselves, which have a notion of positive and negative), then it takes on the negative of that value at $-u$.

Understanding what it means for the derivative at a point to be a linear map is probably the most important thing you need to know to move forward right now, so go ahead an spend some time thinking about the meaning and implications.

Comment: Did the question stipulate that the function $f$ is differentiable at $c$?